# Cancel ccTouch on State Change in Cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Could someone please help with with this issue that I am having with canceling touch event when my character dies. I have Character controller (Touch a sprite and drag left/right to move) based on screen X-axis. My controller class is a subclass of CCNode and has all the required methods to register touch with TouchDispatcher. The ccTouchBegin, ccTouchMove & ccTouchEnd works fine, but while my ccTouchMove is in action and my character dies I want to reset the controller, player position to a start location on the screen but that does not trigger until I lift my finger(thus ccTouchEnd) triggers then my reset player/controller in my GameLayer(CCLayer) fires.

I thought by adding the CCTouchCancel method would do the trick but it is not getting fired. Each of my Touch event methods first checks the controller's state (IDLE, ACTIVE, STOP) before doing any actions. I have an update method also to handle the dragging but it also checks that the controller.state == ACTIVE before allowing player to drag/move character.

In my Gamelayer's update method when my character dies, I set the controller.state = STOP. In the Controller's update method for STOP state, I call `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];` which is the same code in the `onExit` method, but the touch event is not canceling. Touch event is only stopping if I lift my finger. Then the state change made in Gamelayer fires

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my character's controller was not changing state to STOP when my character dies. I had implemented the CCTouchCancel method but it was not getting triggered, thus the touch event was never cancelling until I lifted my finger off the screen.

I had implemented the update: (ccTime)delta method, in which I checking for ACTIVE state and performing some action. After commenting out the update method, everything worked as I expected. There was no need for the update method as the CCTouchMove method handles continuous touched location detection as long as the finger is touching the screen, no need to run an update method.